# How a Fragment can be associated with a Context?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the documentation of the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` class (not the framework's class) for the `getActivity()` method stated that the returned value may be `null` if **the Fragment is associated with a Context.**

How an Fragment can be associated with a Context? Is not the `FragmentManager` the only way to attach an Fragment to something? But the `FragmentManager` can be obtained only from `Activity`. Or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How an Fragment can be associated with a Context?

You must have heard of [FragmentHostCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentHostCallback.html). If you haven't check out the link.

In a simple way, it is an integration point with a **Fragment Host**. When I say Fragment Host, *It is an object that can hold Fragments*. For example an `Activity`. In order to host a fragment - one must implement `FragmentHostCallback`.

However, I haven't come up with any ideas about how Fragment can be implemented in non-activity objects. Will see in future may be...

So that way, **[getActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#) will return `null` on non-activity objects.**

PS,
 
Always go for [getContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getContext()) if you are requiring context rather than activity

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you need the context inside of a fragment.. If so have you checked the method `getContext()` method inside of a fragment?

Also `getActivity()` can be `null` if you are referencing it when the fragment is not attached to an activity. Have a check of the fragment lifecycle to learn more.

Hope I helped

Comment: @vadim in that case, maybe you can implement a callback from the fragment to the activity, and then do what ever you need with the activityManager inside the activity.. this makes much more sence, rather than getting activity instance inside the fragment.

Comment: @vadim How do u mean subclassing them? Maybe if you share your code, we can find an issue..